# Cant sculpt parts of mesh

Tags: mesh, sculpt, dynamic-topology, sculpt-mode

I am not able to sculpt properly in the middle of my mesh. Around it I use Dyntopo of 50 and it works fine but as soon as I get to the middle it does almost no changes whatsoever.

I cant figure out what is different about that part... It looks diferent, but that might be because its esentially flat surface...

Originally the mesh was 2 separate meshes , but I merged them by selecting each edge and filling (pressing F). The result was the mesh you see now and the middle part is the filled regions.

Things I tried:

- Apply all transforms
- Clear sculpt mask data
- Clear split normals data
- Increasing dyntopo
- Remove sharps
- Toggled flat and smooth surface

EDDIT: here is blender file with just the problem mesh:
https://pasteall.org/blend/3a8c1a0fe39e49a7960bdf74ddfda235

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (at least this part)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I updated the original post with the blender file.

Comment: you need to recalculate the normals (in Edit mode, select all and press Shift N), maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: Yes that was it ! I feel so stupid now... There are so many little things to keep track of and this one completely escaped from my head.  Thanks allot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recalculate the normals: in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>